# How to pass params in axios PUT request?

Tags: axios, loopbackjs, put

```
axios.put('http://localhost:3000/api/userDatas/findUserAddProp',{
    params: {
        userId: "5bb8c3bd16bf1f515ce5b42f",
        prop: "questions",
        questionId: "5bb8c466cb49d8421c05eeda"
    }
});
```

Server

```
Userdatas.findUserAddProp = function(req, res, cb) {
    const queryId = req.query.userId;
    const propToUpdate = req.query.prop;
    const questionId = req.query.questionId;

    console.log("queryId: ", queryId);
    console.log("propToUpdate: ", propToUpdate);
    console.log("questionId: ", questionId);
    ...
}
```

Here is the the server output on the console.

```
queryId:  undefined
propToUpdate:  undefined
questionId:  undefined
```

Why is that happening i just passed all params to the server?

Comment: Please check `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

the put method expects an extra parameter "data" (sent in request body):

```
axios.put(url[, data[, config]])
```

pass it as null and you're done:

```
axios.put('http://localhost:3000/api/userDatas/findUserAddProp', **null,** {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can open Axios Interface

```
put<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
```

The Put method recieve the config after the data so you can do:

```
axios.put('http://localhost:3000/api/userDatas/findUserAddProp',
  // Add null here in the data,
   null,
   // then you can give params in the config 
  { params: { /* your params goes here */ }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
req.params.userId
```

**req.param** is used to read Url Params like `/user/:id` whereas **req.query** is used to read query parameters like `http:localhost:8080/api/users?id=123`

Comment: Thank you @ SaqibHussain. I think your explanation and your suggestion contradicts.

Comment: can you share how you're handling this request on the server side?